# c# passing value from asp.net website to windows forms

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, post

I have made a website and a windows forms app both are connected to same MySQL database. The windows app makes a POST request to the website with parameters(username etc).The server(website) generates a pair of RSA public key and private key.The private key is stored in database and the public key is sent to client(windows app).The problem is that when I try to send the public key, it is not being sent . It sends other info like the html code of webpage along with public key and I get error"Invalid syntax" while encryption (obviously because of html code along with public key being sent).How do I only extract the public key and send only that to the client. But I get this output: http://postimg.org/image/8kwpnl6lp/

What am I doing wrong .How can I only get the public key as response from server.amy help is appreciated thanks

Here is my code:

client side(windows app:making post request to server):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string Url = "http://localhost:8731/ckey.aspx"; //creates public key 
    string userName = Textbox1.TExt;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string publicKey = getPublicKey(Url);
      richTextBox1.Text =publicKey ;          
    }
    public string getPublicKey(string url)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
        formData["username"] = userName;            
        byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(url, "POST", formData);          
        string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
        webClient.Dispose();          
        return responsefromserver;
    }
}
```

and the server side code(generates rsa key pair and send public key to client [ckey.aspx])

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string response = AssignNewKey();
    Response.Write(response); 
}

public string AssignNewKey()
{

    string username1 =Request.Form["username"];        
    RSA rsa1 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
    string publicPrivateKeyXML = rsa1.ToXmlString(true);
    string publicOnlyKeyXML = rsa1.ToXmlString(false);        

    using (MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO securelogin (PrivateKey,username)";
        query += " VALUES (@PrivateKey,@username)";
        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, myConn);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrivateKey", publicPrivateKeyXML);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username1);            
        myConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConn.Close();           
    }
    return publicOnlyKeyXML;   
}
```

Comment: You return publicOnlyKeyXML but not using its result in the calling method

Comment: I dont understand what you say.should I use Response.write in the Page_load after calling the method to return value?

Comment: tried that it still sends other info like the html code of the page along with rsa public key.

Comment: That's not enough to solve your problem. You are using System.Web.UI.Page which renders html. You must use something like WebMethod

Comment: how can I use that? I am new to these things..

Comment: I am preparing you answer and post it

Comment: thanks so much it will help me to learn and understand more easily

Comment: If you are passing response by Response.Write, then you should consider adding Response.End/Close. otherwise it will add page HTML too. same we do to send/download file.

Comment: Just exlain in method Page_Load -you do not want nothing instead of your text
 `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Write("my supersecure public key");
            Response.End();
        }`

Comment: done....thanks both of you ...really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing response by `Response.Write`, then you should consider adding `Response.End/Close`. same we do to `send/download` file. 
otherwise it will render page and add page HTML too.

Answer (score -1):

You should use something like WebService (.asmx)

Read this tutorial:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_web_services.htm

Comment: none of the answers help me to solve my problem... :(